# Javascript: read number of any value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply a tooltip to a foreach loop, but I need the javascript to read the attribute "mystickytooltip" with a number at the end.

```
<div id="mystickytooltip{$smarty.foreach.cart.iteration}" class="stickytooltip">
```

Will output

```
<div id="mystickytooltip1" class="stickytooltip">
<div id="mystickytooltip2" class="stickytooltip">
<div id="mystickytooltip3" class="stickytooltip">
```

And I need the javascript to read "mystickytooltip(ANYVALUE)" is this possible? My JS knowledge sucks.

```
//stickytooltip.init("targetElementSelector", "tooltipcontainer")
stickytooltip.init("*[data-tooltip]", "mystickytooltip")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your previous (now deleted) question, it looked like you were using jQuery.  If that's the case, you should just be able to use a class selector:

```
var myToolTips = $("div.mystickytooltip");
```

Or you could use the [`Attribute Starts With`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
var myToolTips = $("div[id^='mystickytooltip']");
```

The only possible drawback I could forsee with the attr-starts-with selector is if you have any other div elements whose id begins with "mystickytooltip" (ie, "mystickytooltipcontainer").  In that case you could combine the class and attr-starts-with selectors:

```
var myToolTips = $("div.mystickytooltip[id^='mystickytooltip']");
```

Comment: This looks like it could be the one, but just a noob js question, I'd just add this in place of where "stickytooltip.init("*[data-tooltip]", "mystickytooltip")" is yes?

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: It looks like you've not followed the instructions correctly for the sticky tooltips script you linked to in Alsciende's comments.  After a brief read of that page it appears you have the structure of the tooltips confused.

Comment: I am not surprised haha. Told yo umy JS knowledge is like, literally none. I built some array once a couple of years ago. This is way out of my league. I shall see ifI can get an example working in jsbin.com

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aquka/edit here, this works as per the example, just need to add it to my smarty foreach loop..

Comment: I've abandoned this solution and gone with a much simpler CSS only tooltip. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Answer accepted as most useful to figuing out I misunderstood the structures.

Comment: Hey @Kyle: sorry, I was out for a meeting, glad you found a good solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var i=1; // starting index
while(document.getElementById('mystickytooltip'+i)) {
  stickytooltip.init("*[data-tooltip]", "mystickytooltip"+(i++));
}
```

In english : as long as you can find an element with id `'mysticktooltip'+i` (+ is string concatenation in js), call `stickytooltip.init` with this id as second parameter (and increment `i`).

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. The page is at www.euroworker.no/order (Add items to basket (more than one) with Kjøp and Handlevogn)

Comment: Canæt say, it just didn't work. I'm using an example from http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/stickytooltip.htm